# getting values from multiple same keyword parameter in request

Tags: python

I have a request like below
`http://127.0.0.1:8090/catalogue/search_detail?d_code=C--755070&ci=2013-06-15&co=2013-06-17&code=123&pax=1,1,2&pax=1`

as you see i have multiple from pax kw parameter. I want to get values from those pax parameters differently.

But when I do

```
self.request.GET.get('pax')
```

It gives me `1` as result that is the latest `pax value`. Is there any way to iterate or get all the pax parameters.

When I say `self.request.GET`, I get answer `<QueryDict: {u'code': [u'26303'], u'co': [u'2013-06-17'], u'ci': [u'2013-06-15'], u'pax': [u'1,1,2,', u'1'], u'd_code': [u'C--755070']}>`

Comment: try "a=self.request.GET" then "a['pax']" you will get list so you could access any value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.request.GET.getlist('pax')` solved my problem. It returns a list consist of pax parameters.

Comment: On a tangent, for 99% of the time, I recommend request.REQUEST rather than GET/POST specific. The number I've times that's gotten me...